# Sitecore 8.2 and AWS Reserved Instances

Tags: cloud, amazon-web-services

Anyone know of any issues running Sitecore 8.2 with AWS Reserved Instances for SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't mean [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/), then it is just another IaaS server instance. There is no issue at all running SQL on them at all.